# Storing settings for a nuget package. Is there a better way?

Tags: c#, nuget

I have a [console application that is available via nuget](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Humpback) or [on it's own](https://github.com/jasonmw/Humpback). It gets installed into the tools directory for the NuGet package.  The application requires 3 pieces of 'configuration' information.

- a database connection string
- a folder path
- one more configuration option (string)

Currently, I store these configuration values in a text file right next to the exe in a file called settings.js, serialized as json.

When the application first runs, if the file is not present, it creates one with default values.

I keep the settings.js file in this location so the file will get checked into source control.

My question is about maintaining the settings file across versions.
If you Update-Package via nuget, everything works great, except the new version doesn't have any settings i had configured, because there is a new folder created for the new version.

I have written a powershell script to run in init.ps1 to pull the settings from the last version of the package, and seems to work.  However this feels kinda dirty and I am wondering if there is a better way to solve this problem when using nuget to deliver my application.

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package)
Set-Alias hump (Join-Path $toolsPath hump.exe)

$sorted_list = new-object system.collections.SortedList
$parent_path = Join-Path $installPath ".."
foreach($f in Get-ChildItem $parent_path -Filter Humpback* | Foreach {$_.FullName}){
    $sorted_list.Add($f,$f)
}
if($sorted_list.Count -gt 1){
    $old_path = $sorted_list.Values[$sorted_list.Count - 2]
    $new_path = Join-Path $installPath "tools"
    $current_settings = Join-Path $new_path "settings.js"
    $has_current_settings = Test-Path $current_settings
    if($has_current_settings -eq $false){
        $old_settings = Join-Path $old_path "tools\settings.js"
        Copy-Item $old_settings  $new_path
    }
}
```

Also, init.ps1 doesn't appear to run when installing a package using the command line tool (nuget.exe). Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you access System.Environment.GetFolderPath?  I'd just create a folder under ApplicationData special folder, and store the settings there.

Comment: i had stayed away from this because i wanted to keep the settings file able to be checked in to source control.  But after thinking about it, that just creates another issue around different users environments when checking in and out of source control. I am going to consider the implications of this for a bit (in regards to the app functionality), but really think this could be a good way to handle this.

Comment: I have implemented this as the fall back if there is no local settings.js, where the local settings file can override the application settings version, just like assembly resolution.  And a new install will create the file in the application settings directory, so you would have to explicitly put a local one there to override it.  This seems to be working great, and helps me support more scenarios.  Thanks for the answer!